# Change UIImage on UIButton with separate Swift file if loop

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uiimage

***Goal of the code:***

To change a `UIButton's` `UIImage` that was already set on `viewDidLoad()` using an outside function that is **not** in `viewDidLoad()`, that is in an entirely separate swift file in the project.

I am however able to successfully change the `UIImage` of the `UIButton` by linking the button to a function that does the standard `exampleButton.setImage(exampleButtonimage, for: .normal)`.

Code below:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    static let vcShared = ViewController()

        var exampleButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 146, y: 140, width: 100, height: 50))
        let exampleButtonimage = UIImage(named: "ExampleImage")
        ...
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        exampleButton.setImage(exampleButtonimage , for: .normal)
  }
}
```

Attempting to set `UIButton's` `UIImage` in the Second file:

```
 let otherButtonimage = UIImage(named: "OtherImage")
    if someVariable > 55000 {
            ViewController.vcShared.exampleButton.setImage(otherButtonimage , for: .normal)
}
```

When the `if` criteria is met, the `UIButton` in `viewDidLoad()` does not change its image (I know the `if` criteria is met as I have a separate `print("Hello World")` in the `if` loop that consistently works.) However, nothing happens with the `UIButton` when the criteria is met.

Comment: Using a singleton pattern doesn't ensure here that `viewDidLoad` has already been executed. If the second file condition is executed before `ViewController` has been presented, then `otherButtonimage` will be overwritten with `exampleButtonimage`. 

Also you should double check that it runs on main thread. UI changes on other thread won't be reflected.

Comment: The second file condition is executed long after the `ViewController` and the `viewDidLoad()` has loaded. It is manually triggered while in the app. I think that the second part just might be my answer. I am able to successfully get it to work while using an `add target` for the actual click of the `UIButton`, but any attempt to change it outside of the `ViewController` fails. Is there a way to quickly make the `if` request go on the main thread? @Ben

Comment: Also, any ideas on a quick way of making the above code work? @Ben

Comment: Another viable solution, though not as elegant, is to simply be able to "reload" the `viewDidLoad()` for a certain section (where the original `UIImage` was set)? That's the `UIImage` I'm trying to "reset" it to. Not sure if there's an easier method for that. @Ben

Comment: If it's for testing, you can execute within a closure with `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`.

Comment: Interesting that you said that, as I had just put that into my code to try and it also didn't work. I don't receive any compile errors, it just still does not change the image, even though this was supposed to run on the main thread. @Ben `DispatchQueue.main.async {
    ViewController.vcShared.exampleButton.setImage(otherButtonimage, for: .normal)
    ViewController.vcShared.exampleButton.setNeedsDisplay()
    ViewController.vcShared.exampleButton.setNeedsLayout()
    }`

Comment: If it's not a thread issue, you can create a breakpoint in both functions, making sure it's the same button (and pointer) by inspecting the memory address. If it's exact same one, you can try to change other button properties to isolate if it's an issue with the image or with other button, and so on.

Comment: Add the code for another file and the code where ViewController of pushed or presented.

Comment: Can you elaborate? @PGDev

Comment: Update your question with more code.

Comment: Trying to determine what other code is relevant, as I think I have all the elements of this particular problem laid out in the above code. I'm thinking it might be as Ben described, where the issue lies in the fact that I'm trying to update it from a separate file. What would you need to help troubleshoot? The class where the loop is? It's an extremely long and complex loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is cosntruct delegate or observer pattern for that situation but the code below is going to work your code.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static var exampleButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 146, y: 140, width: 100, height: 50))
    let exampleButtonimage = UIImage(named: "ExampleImage")
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    exampleButton.setImage(exampleButtonimage , for: .normal)}}
```

And where change code;

```
     let otherButtonimage = UIImage(named: "OtherImage")
     if someVariable > 55000 {
       ViewController.exampleButton.setImage(otherButtonimage , for: .normal)}
```

Comment: MY MAN. THANK YOU! Worked like a charm! **For anyone else wondering what was causing the issue, changing the variable to a "static" variable across the board fixed the issue**